# epsg 4269 to epsg 3161 and vice versa

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.5

Having difficulty in arcmap 10.5 changing projections from GCS_North_American_1983 WKID: 4269 Authority: EPSG to NAD_1983_Ontario_MNR_Lambert WKID: 3161 Authority: EPSG. Every attempt constantly displays the newly projected data outside the view extent of the current Arcmap layer even with the new projection. To view the new projected data I have to use "zoom to layer"  then zoom to layer back to the data in my layer.